# Please help me with a simple c++ std::time_t question

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the current time and subtract a set amount of seconds to find a time in the past. See my code example below...

```
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
   uint32_t sec = 100;
   std::time_t t = std::time(NULL);
   std::time_t mt  = t - (std::time_t)sec;
   struct std::tm* currTime = std::localtime( &t);
   printf( "Current Time  %s\n", asctime(currTime) );
   struct std::tm* modTime = std::localtime( &mt);
   printf( "Modified Time %s\n", asctime(modTime) );
   printf( "Current Time  %s\n", asctime(currTime) );
}
```

Initially it seems like it works with the first two prints, but the third print is the same as the second print.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Output:

```
Current Time  Thu Oct 29 18:10:39 2020

Modified Time Thu Oct 29 18:08:59 2020

Current Time  Thu Oct 29 18:08:59 2020
```

Comment: I think it's because you have a ptr to the current time. Try saving the time in another variable.

Comment: `struct std::tm modTime = *std::localtime( &mt);` instead of `struct std::tm* modTime = std::localtime( &mt);` and then `printf( "Modified Time %s\n", asctime(&modTime) );`   Sample: https://onlinegdb.com/ryUbOJF_v

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thanks yep I missed the pointer part, that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) for `localtime(3)`:

> The return value points to a statically allocated  struct  which  might  be
> overwritten  by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions.

Your `localtime` always returns a pointer to the ***same internal object***, and each time it gets called it overwrites its contents and returns the same pointer.

So, both of your pointers end up pointing to the same object, with the same contents.

As the manual page explains, there's an alternative `localtime_r` library call that does not suffer this limitation, but you have to do more work to use it.